# How to setup Rails application without a GemFile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I've downloaded a rails example app from github, but it has no GemFile, how could I make it run?
I tried `rake gems:install`, and got the following errors. I couldn't figure out why, anyone can help? thanks very much!

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from G:/Desktop/20090319-/Rails Examples/showchart/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
...
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/gemsonrails/tasks, vendor/plugins/gemsonrails/tasks, vendor/plugins/gemsonrails/tasks, vendor/plugins/gemsonrails/tasks, and vendor/plugins/open_flash_chart/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from <top (required)> at G:/Desktop/20090319-/Rails Examples/showchart/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
** Invoke gems:install (first_time)
** Invoke gems:base (first_time)
** Execute gems:base
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "RedCloth":String
G:/Desktop/20090319-/Rails Examples/showchart/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:277:in `=='
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `block in matching_specs'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `block in each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
....
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

Comment: Can you provide the github path, where u have downloaded the example app

Answer (score 0):

Just copy/past a Gemfile from a new rails app, then start the application and try to figure out which gem is missing... :-S